# How do i exclude certain file paths in a bash script

Tags: bash

i was wondering if anyone could help me.

i am writing a program that looks in directories for a certain file. i have multiple directories inside a project folder some contain the file and others don't.

```
project 
    folderwithfile1
    folderwithfile2
    folderwithfile3
    folderwithoutfile
```

if this file exists in one of these folders, my program will sanitizes the file path to remove the filename result would be

```
home/newcoder/Desktop/project/folderwithfile1
home/newcoder/Desktop/project/folderwithfile2
home/newcoder/Desktop/project/folderwithfile3
```

now i would like to exclude/ignore certain folders from the search even if they contain the file. for example lets exclude folderwithfile1 and folderwithfile2.

my current code is

```
exclusionFilePaths=('/home/newcoder/Desktop/project/folderwithfile1' '/home/newcoder/Desktop/project/folderwithfile2')

for i in $(find ~+ -type f -name "fileWantToFind.php")
do
    sanitized=${i%/*}

for key in "${exclusionFilePaths[@]}";
do  
    if [ $sanitized == $key ]
    then 
       echo $sanitized
       #ignore and continue
    else
       echo veryLongCommand

    fi

  done
done
```

the result of my program is this

```
no
/home/newcoder/Desktop/project/folder1
/home/newcoder/Desktop/project/folder3
/home/newcoder/Desktop/project/folder3
/home/newcoder/Desktop/project/folder2
no
```

what am i doing wrong ?
any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: FYI, `for file in $(find ...)` [is itself an antipattern](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29). For the safe/correct way to use find, see the _Actions in Bulk_ section of [Using Find](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind)

Comment: Also, `echo $sanitized` is buggy for the reasons given in [I just assigned a variable, but `echo $variable` shows something else!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else), and `if [ $sanitized == $key ]` should be `if [ "$sanitized" = "$key" ]` -- but personally, I'd modify your `find` command so it never goes down those paths at all, which is something `-prune` is suited for.

Comment: It's also _much_ more efficient if you invert your array and make the paths the keys, not the values. If you have `declare -A valuesToExclude=( ["firstValue"]=1 ["secondValue"]=1 ["thirdValue"]=1 )` then it's a constant-time lookup with no iteration needed to check `[[ "${valuesToExclude[$valueToCheck]}" ]]` to see if `valueToCheck` is one of `firstValue`/`secondValue`/`thirdValue`.

Comment: @NewCoder – _what_ you are _doing wrong_ is that you named the folders `folder1..3`, while `exclusionFilePaths` are `…folderwithfile1..3`.

Answer (score 1):

Example of using `find -prune` with some small cleanups.

```
#!/bin/bash
exclusionFilePaths=(
'/home/newcoder/Desktop/project/folderwithfile1' 
'/home/newcoder/Desktop/project/folderwithfile2'
)

# Build the required predicate for find to -prune undesired directories
exclusionArgs=( "(" "-path" "${exclusionFilePaths[0]}" )
for (( idx=1 ; idx < "${#exclusionFilePaths[@]}" ; idx++ )) ; do
  exclusionArgs+=( "-o" "-path" "${exclusionFilePaths[idx]}" )
done
exclusionArgs+=( ")" "-prune" )

# Use find -print0 to print all the remaining instances of fileWantToFind,
# then read and process them in a loop
while read -r -d '' line ; do
  sanitized="${line%/*}"
  veryLongCommand
done < <( find ~+ "${exclusionArgs[@]}" -o -name fileWantToFind.php -print0 )
# Important stuff:   ^^ predicate+prune ^^ OR   ^^ thing we want    ^  
#                                                                   |
#                                                         overrides implicit print
#                                                         when only action is -prune
```

Comment: Include the `IFS=` to avoid truncating trailing/leading whitespace of the filepath, so the line should be something like`while IFS='' read -r -d '' line ; do`. But it seems like your code will work without it.

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude dirs in `find`

```
find ~+ -type f -name fileWantToFind.php -not \( -path /home/newcoder/Desktop/project/folderwithfile1/\* -o -path /home/newcoder/Desktop/project/folderwithfile2/\* \)
```

Comment: More efficient to use `-prune` and stop going down the paths at all instead of finding files in them but then discarding them.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy totally agree

Answer (score 0):

thank you everyone for your contribution, sorry this update is a little late.
The posts by **Diego Torres Milano** and **tjm3772**, were incredibly helpful and i learnt a great deal, from their examples.
while both **Diego Torres Milano** and **tjm3772** examples worked, i decided to put my excludedDomainPaths in a separate file, and loop through it with a for loop.
if anyone is curios this is my code.

```
for domainPath in $(find ~+ -type f -name "fileIWantToFind" ) do
    sanitizedDomain=${domainPath%/*}
    for excludedDomain in $(cat exclusionFile)
    do
        if [[ $sanitizedDomain == $excludedDomain ]]
            then
            continue 2 
        fi
    done
    echo very long command done
```

i know there are probably some better ways of doing this code, but for now i am happy with were i am, we all have to start somewhere after all.

thank you everyone.